# Not able to access application inside kubernetes POD

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-pod

[Service.Yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf1qe.png)

[pods.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckTMF.png)

i am not able to access my application from browser. What mistake i am doing ?

if i give Ipaddress:30010 -> my app is not getting reached. (attached my pod.yaml and service.yaml here in attachment)

Comment: what exactly do you expect to happen when you call a db connection port with a webbrowser?

Comment: How are you trying to access the database ? pgAdmin or psql or any other way.

Comment: It looks like you've included two links to image files of some sort instead of including the Kubernetes YAML files as text in your question; can you edit the question to fix this?  What's the exact URL you're connecting to; where does the IP address come from?  What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `targetPort` setting in the ports section on your Service.yaml. This specifies the destination port of the container.

```
ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
    nodePort: 30010
```

`port` is a setting for in-cluster communication, that other containers in the cluster can access via `{serviceName}:port`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find your node ip. If you are using minikube then you find node ip list. By running kubectl cluster-info. Then in your browser go to http:[node-ip]:30010